# Prisma relations with same field

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, relational-database, prisma

I have to do the relation between these 2 tables:

```
model Challenge {
  id              String           @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid
  user_challenges UserChallenges[]
  winners         UserChallenges[] @relation("ChallengeWinners")
  
  @@map("challenges")
}

model UserChallenges {
  challenge_id String     @db.Uuid
  user_id      String     @db.Uuid
  challenge    Challenge  @relation(fields: [challenge_id], references: [id])
  winners      Challenge? @relation("ChallengeWinners", fields: [challenge_id], references: [id])
  

  @@map("user_challenges")
}
```

but the @relation in the UserChalenges table return me an error that says:
"Error parsing attribute "@relation": The given constraint name `user_challenges_challenge_id_fkey` has to be unique in the following namespace: on model `UserChallenges` for primary key, indexes, unique constraints and foreign keys. Please provide a different name using the `map` argument.".

It shouldn't work with the alias made? Why is it trying to get the same fkey?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have relations with the same field. In this case, the `user_challenges` and `winners` may be different users, so you need different fields like this:

```
model Challenge {
  id              String           @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid
  user_challenges UserChallenges[]
  winners         UserChallenges[] @relation("ChallengeWinners")

  @@map("challenges")
}

model UserChallenges {
  challenge_id        String     @db.Uuid
  challenge_winner_id String     @db.Uuid
  user_id             String     @db.Uuid
  challenge           Challenge  @relation(fields: [challenge_id], references: [id])
  winners             Challenge? @relation("ChallengeWinners", fields: [challenge_winner_id], references: [id])


  @@map("user_challenges")
}
```

Comment: Can you help me one more time?

I have a problem that is: the winner must be one user_challenges that already exists, I'll not create e new one just to be a winner, he is already in that table and I just want to relate it as a winner.

Is it possible to use the same field 2 times anyway?

Thanks.